# What changes can you make to an EXE written like a DLL to make it a DLL?

Tags: python, dll, exe

I am looking at different ways of using python to make a dll.  One suggestion I ran into was to use py2exe to compile the code to an exe and then rename it as a DLL and call it with the program.  I have searched for other discussion as to whether this would work, and from what I have read it seems like you'd have to do more than just change the name and call it from another file, but I have not seen an explicit answer either way.

Obviously I'd like a little explanation as to why this can or cannot be done. What changes can you make to an EXE written like a DLL to make it a DLL? (like editing the PE header).

Comment: Not completely a duplicate because it's quite c++-specific, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865631/c-loading-an-exe-as-a-dll-local-vftable-problem?rq=1 might be helpful? That is an interesting question.

Comment: I doubt it is even possible.  I imagine that py2exe isn't creating entry points for your functions the way a C/C++ compiler does.